# Is there a WordPress API or feed that returns all comments for a specified author?

Tags: api, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to access all comments authored by a specific user.  I know there is a feed for all comments regardless of user (http://example.com/comments/feed/) but is there a way to limit comments to a certain user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_comments()` function allows you to pass in an array of parameters to filter on - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

To get all comments for user_ID 1, you would use:

```
$args = array( 'ID' => 1 );
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

The result will be an array of comment objects that match your search criteria. You can use multiple filters at once, for example the user ID in conjunction with a status.